# Accessing SQL Server gives error - ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2012, connection

I have SQL Server 2012 and Oracle 11g installed on the same virtual machine and OS is Windows Server 2012. I am trying to connect Oracle to SQL Server. I have kept the machines same in the hopes that process will be easier. I created the machine 2 days ago to test the connection process before applying it on server.

Following are the steps I have taken.

1) Created ODBC Connection for SQL Server with the name **sqlodbc** with the simple/non-admin user credentials which is tested successfully.

2) My tnsnames.ora file is below

```
sqlodbc
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1433))
(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = sqlodbc))
(HS = OK)
)
```

**[SQL Server port is 1433]** **[I even tried with the port 1521 but same problem]**

3) The `SID_LIST_LISTENER` part from listener.ora file is as follow

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
(SID_NAME=sqlodbc)
(ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
(PROGRAM = hsodbc)
)
)
```

4) I have created **initsqlodbc.ora** file at **[Oracle_Home]\hs\admin** with following

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = sqlodbc
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = off
```

5) I created the public database link

```
create public database link sqls 
connect to "user" identified by "pass" 
using 'sqlodbc';
```

I went through other threads on here but I could not find any solution for my problem.

I am trying to run the following command

```
select * from empnew@sqls
```

Where have I gone wrong with the configuration? Or if there is any step that I have missed? Or I have taken the wrong approach altogether?

I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you.

**[NOTE: When I restarted the machine, and I tried running the same command, I was getting the "Database not open error" initially but then it changed into the TNS error later on after a minute or so.]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there must have been some syntax error which was giving me the issue.

I recreated the ODBC connection, re-written entries in tnsnames.ora and listener.ora file and removed all the previous commented entries. The spaces and " and brackets can cause problems so just make sure everything is accounted for.

My updated ora files can be found at this location for future references. (its another question for different error but contains all the information in correct format.)
[Issue connecting Oracle 11g to SQL Server 2012 -- ORA-12523: TNS:listener could not find instance appropriate for the client connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558423/issue-connecting-oracle-11g-to-sql-server-2012-ora-12523-tnslistener-could)

Answer (score 0):

Try this TNSNAMES.ora entry instead:

```
sqlodbc
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1433))
(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = sqlodbc))
(HS = OK)
)
```

Comment: Nope. Still the same problem. I followed the Oracle Gateway steps from this website  [link]http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_callan_accessing_sql_server_from_oracle_database.htm and I am getting the same error. I have my firewall turned off too just to make sure noting is blocking the connection.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I also tried the Oracle Gateway today to see if that would work. I tried ODBC process yesterday, I am getting the same error in both.